# How can I add individual classes to my array in twig?

Tags: html, arrays, set, twig, iteration

i want to add an individual class to my array items.

My HTML:

```
{% for post in page.find('/karriere').children.order('date', 'desc').published().slice(0, 4) %}
    <li class="careers-nav-item item">
        <a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}" target="_self">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Now I want to add after the "item" in my li a individual class like:

```
<li class="careers-nav-item item_first">
    <a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}" target="_self">{{ post.title }}</a>
</li>
```

or

```
<li class="careers-nav-item item_second">
    <a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}" target="_self">{{ post.title }}</a>
</li>
```

Do you have any solutions for my problem? And sorry for my bad english :P

Comment: See https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable: `loop.first`.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If so, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

I looked on your profile and saw your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351808/to-compress-my-jquery). Based in that question, I think you don't need to add 'first' or 'second' in the first place. Your question looks like it as the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):

> asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Use [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) instead.

If you want to style the first or second item, add this to your css:

```
//first
p:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
}
//second
p:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Or if you want to style all odd items:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}
```